# How to add table in web page using mathjax

Tags: mathjax

I am a beginner. I am trying to build a table using math Jax but it can't compile. how can I add a table?

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | m{7em} | m{5em}| m{9em} | } 
            \hline
        Set & operation & Identity \\ 
            \hline
        \(\mathbb{Z}\) & \(+\) & \(0\)    \\
            \hline
        \(\mathbb{Q}\) & \(+\) & \(0\)    \\
            \hline
        \(\mathbb{R}\) & \(+\) & \(0\)    \\ 
            \hline

        \(\mathbb{Z}\) & \(\times \) & \(0\)    \\
            \hline
        \(\mathbb{Q}\) & \(\times\) & \(0\)    \\
            \hline
        \(\mathbb{R}\) & \(\times\) & \(0\)    \\ 
            \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 25):

I made a table generator for MathJax using MathJax's array : https://isaurssaurav.github.io/mathjax-table-generator/

Usage:

1. Add required columns and Rows.
2. You can add values to cells when table appears
3. Click Generate button to generate a mathjax code for table.

Repo Link :https://github.com/isaurssaurav/mathjax-table-generator 
( Any changes are welcome )
[image]

Comment: N.B. this uses 'array' which is semantically different from 'tabular' in latex. so many latex users would think of it differently... But sure - it looks like a table indeed.

Comment: I get an error, `Misplaced \hline`. **Update:** Never mind, it was a Markdown issue. Had to do quadruple backslashes instead of double.

Answer (score 15):

MathJax only implements the macros used for math layout, not text layout, so things like `\begin{tabular}` and `\begin{center}` are not supported.  Instead, you can use an `array` environment, like:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full"></script>

\[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{Set} & \text{Operation} & \text{Identity} \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{Z} & + & 0 \\
\hline
   \mathbb{Q} & + & 0 \\
\hline
   \mathbb{R} & + & 0 \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{Z} & \times & 1 \\
\hline
   \mathbb{Q} & \times & 1 \\
\hline
   \mathbb{R} & \times & 1 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
\]
```

On the other hand, it may be better to use an HTML table with math inside it rather than trying to use MathJax to do the entire table.

Comment: I agree it's best to use an HTML table. If we don't use any HTML, we're writing the entire document in TeX!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline a & c \\ \hline b & d \\ \hline  \end{array}$$`