# Mix of text and math formula on HTML page

Tags: html, css, mathjax

I have a task to write something like this on HTML page:

[image: Example text with usage of formula]

Math tag (of HTML) is not good because it couldn't deal with the tag break in between parts `"/begin()-/end()"`. So, creating something like this (working great at LaTeX):

```
$
\left\lbrace
\begin{matrix}
  $Option1$\\
  $Option2$
\end{matrix}
\right\rbrace
$
```

In HTML:

```
<p><span class="math inline">\(\left\lbrace
\begin{matrix}\)</span>
Option1
<span class="math inline">\(\\
\)</span>
Option2
<span class="math inline">\(\end{matrix}
\right\rbrace\)</span></p>
```

Is not working. /begin and /end are in different spans and it is breaking LaTeX internal process. I need to take out options from math tags, because I need to apply my own formatting to them. Funny part: If I'll use CSS

```
.math {
}
```

It could change color and size, but not font famaly or italic/bold format.

Using the HTML table structure is also not helping because `{}` symbols are not covering full height of options part (number of elements could rise up to 7).

As result I'm out of possible solutions here. May somebody share idea how I could cover this task? If possible I want to avoid SVG/PNG or any other image type for support of different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51803630/3543233), Davide Cervone states:

> MathJax only implements the macros used for math layout, not text layout, so things like `\begin{tabular}` and `\begin{center}` are not supported. Instead, you can use an array environment [...]

This is why we can't use all the environments. The following code should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MathJax</title>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
\(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    \left\lbrace
    \begin{matrix}
      \mathrm{Option1}\\
      \mathrm{Option2}
    \end{matrix}
    \right\rbrace & %
%
    your\ content & %
%
    \begin{matrix}
      \mathrm{type1}\\
      \mathrm{type2}\\
      \mathrm{type3}
    \end{matrix}\\
  \end{array}
\)
</body>
</html>
```

**Snippet:**

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

\(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    \left\lbrace
    \begin{matrix}
      \mathrm{Option1}\\
      \mathrm{Option2}
    \end{matrix}
    \right\rbrace & %
%
    your\ content & %
%
    \begin{matrix}
      \mathrm{type1}\\
      \mathrm{type2}\\
      \mathrm{type3}
    \end{matrix}\\
  \end{array}
\)
```

---

The same post that I linked above also advises to use HTML tables as much as possible, rather than LaTeX `array`s or other. The following sketch with two sets of `<table>`s nested makes more complicate to render the braces but it's still ok. The use of `<table>` should anyway be not exceeded and limited to only present data in tabular format.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>No MathJax</title>
<style>td.braces{font-size:200%}</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="braces">{</td>
          <td>Option1</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="braces">}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Option2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>your content</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>type1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>type2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>type3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Snippet:**

```css
td.braces{font-size:200%}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="braces">{</td>
          <td>Option1</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="braces">}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Option2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>your content</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>type1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>type2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>type3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Only one line of CSS here!

---

Finally, if you like, add some information about how you thought the ideograms should be implemented, so we refine it!

Comment: Hi, @MattAllegro.
Thanks a lot for the answer. Thought so, but still did hope there do exists some workaround solution to use MathJax. Couldn’t use first solution, because it is downloading script from the internet. Installation where I’m using it doesn’t have access to the internet :(

Comment: Regarding tables: yes, I’m already using this approach. But the problem is dynamic lines number. So, just placing 200% is not good for me. Currently I’m using a script to calculate number of lines and changing font size depending on it. It would be a little easier if font size could be installed as 100% of the column line height, but this option does not exist. Have been hoping to solve it by using MathJax (writing script is little complicated for this problem), but looks it is not an option too.
Still, thanks a lot for information. It did confirm my thoughts.

Comment: @AllertGen you're welcome! You can also download the MathJax js file and link to the local copy of it in your (sub)folder.

Comment: @AllertGen Also, to scale the braces, the svg approach this is the last one listed in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/).